# «Скорее всего, в этом году». Запятая нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

> Скорее всего, в этом году.

Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 2):

Сначала правило:
[**скорее всего**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_672), *вводное сочетание*
То же, что «очень вероятно, вероятнее всего».
*Конечно, всё из-за коньяка и парилки, иначе он бы, **скорее всего,** промолчал* (В. Быков. Бедные люди). ***Скорее всего,** зять Малюты Скуратова, создавший несравненный аппарат доносчиков, что-то узнал* (Э. Радзинский. Лжедмитрий). *Это, **скорее всего,** меня не касается* (А. и Б. Стругацкие. Жук в муравейнике).
Не смешивать с употреблением в роли **членов предложения** (в значении «быстрее всего»).
*Этим путем **скорее всего** можно было прийти к дому* ( Д. Григорович. Город и деревня).

Теперь выбор пунктуации.
Ставим запятую, выделяя вводное сочетание.
*— Когда начнете строить?

**— Скорее всего, в этом году.***

Скорее всего, в этом году в Подмосковье можно будет вдоволь пособирать лишь летние и осенние опята. [Грибов в этом году почти не будет // «Вечерняя Москва», 2002.07.18]

Не ставим запятую (можно использовать синонимичное «быстрее всего»).
*— Вы уже много лет живете в пригороде. Долго добираетесь на работу?

**— Скорее всего в этом году.** Пробок почти нет.*

Comment: Минусовщик, отзовись, объяснись, пожалуйста: что же именно в моем ответе не является полезным?

Comment: Я присоединяюсь к просьбе Риммы. Ответ соответствует сведениям из Справочника по пунктуации. на Грамоте.ру. Это неверная  информация? Если это так, то приведите доказательства.  Тогда мы не будем пользоваться этим справочником.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, могу высказать предположение. Этот вопрос вчера был кем-то включен в очередь на закрытие. Вы не только не поддержали предложение закрытия, но и "посмели" дать ответ. У меня недостаточно прав, чтобы увидеть, кто был инициатором попытки закрыть этот вопрос, но могу предположить, что минус поставил он. Я уже много раз сталкивался с ситуациями, когда люди, желающие закрыть вопрос, минусуют тех, кто на него отвечает.

Comment: @Sharon, думаю здесь причина не в содержимом ответа, а в самом факте его наличия.

Comment: Да, я тоже считаю, что это вопрос организационного характера, и такие вопросы не  должны решаться  «голосованием». Определить качество вопроса не так просто, для этого нужно хорошо разбираться не в русском языке вообще, а именно в этой теме. Подобная ситуация наносит вред интересам общества. Я часто отвечаю на такие вопросы (синтаксис, грамматика, пунктуация), но и я не сразу могла определить, к примеру, нужен ли здесь контекст, одно ли решение имеет задача в практических примерах из  Нацкорпуса.

Comment: Я могла бы дополнить ответ Риммы, чтобы получилось интересное и полезное обсуждение, но специально не стала этого делать, чтобы  МОРАЛЬНО не поддерживать «минусовщика». И в результате вместо пользы мы имеем неприятную для всех ситуацию, на что надо бы обратить внимание людям,  уполномоченным в решении таких проблем. Мой же вывод такой: «голосование» не оправдывает себя. Закрывать надо вопросы с очевидными нарушениями по оформлению или содержанию. И закрывать их должны модераторы (или их помощники), причем закрывать сразу, так чтобы ответы на них просто не принимались.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Спасибо, Иван, за поддержку и попытку *понаразобраться* в ситуации. "Дык" и что теперь делать, как же ж быть? Если кто-то один (всего один!) решил закрыть вопрос, то другому, имеющему супротивное мнение, надо много раз подумать — боись, накажут!

Comment: @Sharon И вам, *Sharon*, спасибо за *присоединение*. Да, контекста нет — крутим, вертим, додумываем. Да, можно было добавить в ответ информацию из УФС (https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/993/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE). Но мне показалось, что это не наш вариант.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, к сожалению, ответа на вопрос "что делать" у меня нет. Формально минусующий не нарушает правила, ведь он имеет право ставить минусы любому постингу, не объясняя причин. Взывать к моральным принципам тут тоже бессмысленно: наверняка он искренне верит, что делает благое дело, если готов тратить баллы своей личной репутации, минусуя ответы на не понравившиеся ему вопросы. Скорее всего, авторы этих вопросов для него "враги чистоты сайта", а отвечающие на них - коллаборанты врага. Соответственно, себя такие люди считают "санитарами леса". И с этим ничего нельзя поделать.